# Finding differences of two list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries like below:

```
prev = [ 
  { 'id': 0, 'name': 'a' }, 
  { 'id': 1, 'name': 'b' }, 
  { 'id': 2, 'name': 'c' } 
]

current = [ 
  { 'id': 1, 'name': 'b' }, 
  { 'id': 2, 'name': 'c' }, 
  { 'id': 3, 'name': 'e' }, 
  { 'id': 4, 'name': 'f' } 
]
```

I want to get the difference of them, the result should be like below:

```
result = [ 
  { 'id': 3, 'name': 'e' }, 
  { 'id': 4, 'name': 'f' } 
]
```

Only the difference of those two should appear in result list, mu solution is like below

```
common = []
for c in current:
  for p in prev:
    if c['name'] == p['name']:
      common.append(c)

print(common)
```

I'm trying to find the common items between two and then subtract it from `current` list but I don't know hot to handle it. If I am using the wrong procedure to resolve the issue, is there another way I can find these two diffs?

I tried to search a lot but all the results I found were just comparing two list of integers, which in my case is list of dictionaries.

Also note that the id key is just for separating those items, let's compare by name, let's consider I want to remove commons from `current` and remain the rest just in `current` list. By that I mean that I don't need `name: a` and `name: b` from `prev` list.

Comment: What about `{ 'id': 0, 'name': 'a' }`? It's in `prev` but not `current`.

Comment: i dont need any prev value from `prev` list , i only want new items that comes in `current` list

Comment: also note that in real world i have a link key in both dicts to compare if i could find the not equal links in `current` list then i found the desired items

Comment: What is with duplicate names? Can a `name` not appear under different id's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Simple

From the data you posted, you can compare the whole dicts, so just find dicts in `current` that are not in `prev`:

```
new = [d for d in current if d not in prev]
print(new)  # -> [{'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]
```

#### Complex

If your real-world data might have differing `id`s, the solution needs to get more complex.

Since only the `name`s are important, make a set of common names. Then you can loop over the dicts and check whether the `name` is in the common set.

```
prev = [{'id': 0, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'b'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'c'}]
current = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'b'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'c'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]

prev_names, current_names = [{d['name'] for d in x} for x in (prev, current)]  # [{'c', 'b', 'a'}, {'c', 'b', 'f', 'e'}]
common_names = prev_names & current_names  # {'b', 'c'}
new = [d for d in current if d['name'] not in common_names]
print(new)  # -> [{'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]
```

This is also easy to adapt to getting names in `prev` that are not common:

```
old = [d for d in prev if d['name'] not in common_names]
print(old)  # -> [{'id': 0, 'name': 'a'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job

```py
prev = [ { 'id': 0, 'name': 'a' }, { 'id': 1, 'name': 'b' }, { 'id': 2, 'name': 'c' } ]
current = [ { 'id': 1, 'name': 'b' }, { 'id': 2, 'name': 'c' }, { 'id': 3, 'name': 'e' }, { 'id': 4, 'name': 'f' } ]

common = []
for c in current:
    if not any(c['id'] == p['id'] and c['name'] == p['name'] for p in prev):
        common.append(c)

print(common)
```

> Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False

Alse, as @wjandrea noted in the comments, this

```py
new = [c for c in current if c not in prev]
```

is also a fair and nice answer. But note that it only works if comparing the whole dicts

Comment: Based on OP's code I think the `'id'` actually doesn't matter, but if it does you might as well compare the whole dicts, `any(c == p for p in prev)`

Comment: `common` is the wrong name, maybe `new` would be better?

Comment: @wjandrea yeah right. One can use `c == p` if the whole diet is compared

Comment: @wjandrea used the names in the OP

Comment: I realized you used the names in the OP, but @a_m_dev was trying to create a list of common names first

Comment: Here's a one-line version: `new = [c for c in current if not any(c == p for p in prev)]` **Edit** oh wait, you can simplify this even further: `new = [c for c in current if c not in prev]`

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you want only the items that appear in current and did not appear in prev.

Something like this should work

```
 prev_names = set(map(lambda x: x['name'], prev))
 new_items = [item for item in current if item['name'] not in prev_names]
 new_items # [{'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]
```

Comment: what's the point of using `map` with `lambda` if you are just converting back to a `set`. would be more pythonic to do `set(item['name'] for item in prev)`

Comment: I think that difference is a matter of taste, I would say both are pythonic, but is a valid comment

Comment: actually I disagree, comprehensions are more readable especially in this context, not to mention there is no point of using `map` considering that you convert it into a set anyways

Comment: map is not creating a dict, is just creating an iterator, same as the for, so I don't see the difference. I agree with this "comprehensions are more readable especially in this context", that's why I upvoted ur comment

Comment: where did I say `map` is creating a dictionary? nowhere....

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
import itertools
list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x in prev, current))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]
```

Comment: Simpler: `[d for d in current if d not in prev]`

Comment: @wjandrea :D :D

Comment: @wjandrea despite simplicity, `itertools` is usually faster as it is implemeted in C.

Comment: Not is this particular case though :D

Answer (score 2):

Based on all of the answers here is a little benchmark

```py
import timeit
import itertools

prev = [{'id': 0, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'b'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'c'}]
current = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'b'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'c'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]


def f1():
    prev_names = set(map(lambda x: x['name'], prev))
    new_items = [item for item in current if item['name'] not in prev_names]
    return new_items


def f2():
    common = []
    for c in current:
        if not any(c['id'] == p['id'] and c['name'] == p['name'] for p in prev):
            common.append(c)

    return common


def f3():
    return list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x in prev, current))


print(f1())
print(timeit.timeit("f1()", setup="from __main__ import f1"))
print(f2())
print(timeit.timeit("f2()", setup="from __main__ import f2"))
print(f3())
print(timeit.timeit("f3()", setup="from __main__ import f3"))
```

```py
[{'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]
0.8235890520736575
[{'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]
2.0767332719406113
[{'id': 3, 'name': 'e'}, {'id': 4, 'name': 'f'}]
0.864271447993815
```